# Login to shopping Cart in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

In a web application which I found it has been decided the user must have logged in or registered as a new user before they can either view the shopping cart or place an item in it. So if the user selects an item to add to the cart and they are not logged in, they must be forced to login or register. My question is, what is the main approach to handling this situation in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea (business wise) to only allow the addition of items to cart if the users are logged in, but I leave that to you.

The approach you need to take depends on your specs which aren't 100% clear. I assume your catalog and product pages are public accessible and I expect you want the user to login in with his credentials and also add the item to the cart and then go back to the product page as well?

A use-case of what you want could be the following:

1. If the user clicks on add item to cart, do a postback and check if the user is logged in and - if so - add the item (use-cases ends) otherwise redirect to the login page add remember (session, querystring, cookies) the item you want to add.
2. User enters credentials and the system checks if there is a pending item to add and - if so - adds the item to the cart.
3. The system redirects the user back to the product page.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same approach in every language. You have to handle a login status. If the user is logged you let him add the item. If he is not, when he try to add an item, ask him to loggin or to register. The best way to do that is by session or cookies. When the guy is logged you will have in the session or cookie a variable that tell you: yes he is logged!

Answer (score 1):

Use formsauthentication and membership in ASP.NET

An ideal starter (i found when i started asp.net ecommerce) was the old CSK (Commerce Starter Kit) for asp.net 2.0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check weather the user is logged in or not before they add items to the shoppingcart, it can be done like this:

```
if(!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```